# Getting errorLabels: [ 'TransientTransactionError' ] when using mongodb on my deployed website

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ubuntu, pm2, robo3t

i deployed my website, set mongodb server and it worked good and fine when i was without ssl.
    I created ssl and got https, and now i cant save/ or get anything from database because it gives me:

```
name: 'MongoNetworkError',
errorLabels: [ 'TransientTransactionError' ],
[Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }
```

Maybe the problem is because the https, but maybe it is something different.
    I am using robo3t, and ubuntu for the website.

Comment: can you connect to your database from terminal? Like this: mongo mongodb://user:password@host:port/database

Comment: I just run mongo and it says its connected , i tested it with console log , there is problem with inserting and getting data...

Comment: Have you restart your mongodb instance after adding certificates?

Comment: no...how to do that?

Comment: You need to enter VM on which mongodb working, then run sudo service mongod restart, after this sudo service mongod status, to check that mongo daemon (mongod) not crashed. In case it crashed, need to check /var/log/mongod folder for logs of what is wrong.

Comment: Ok, my mongodb status is failed, i got into /var/log and now i have mongodb file and mongodb.log, how to access and see logs?

Comment: less mongodb.log, then navigate with arrows, also check out vim shortcuts, like gg - to top, GG - to bottom. Otherwise you can use nano, or any other text editor to view it.

Comment: 2019-12-04T14:25:45.370+0000 [clientcursormon]  mapped (incl journal view):320
2019-12-04T14:25:45.370+0000 [clientcursormon]  connections:3
thats the last log...there is similiar to this like thousands of the same log

Comment: No other way but read carefully logs and try to find where is error, why mongod is failed to start.